# How to save ontology separately in different files?

Tags: jena, owl, ontology

I want to save all classes in an OWL file, all individuals in another OWL file. Can anybody tell me how to do so? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To list classes and individuals, two functions are designed as :

```
ExtendedIterator<OntClass> classes = model.listClasses();
ExtendedIterator<Individual> individuals = model.listIndividuals();
```

Be careful that `model` need to be an `OntModel`.

You then need to write your iterators in the desired files.

Here is the link to [OntModel Javadoc](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntModel.html).